# Getting wrong values from serial port in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino, rxtx

I am trying to read values from [**ALGE-TIMING**](http://www.alge-timing.com/alge-e.htm) device connected to the serial port via [**Arduino**](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno).

The Arduino reads the input signal it gets from the ALGE and transmits it to the serial port continuously. The values are in the range from **10-30** when the beam is not cut. When the beam is cut, it sends **0**.

I can see this value in Arduino's Serial Monitor but when I try to read this value through Java, I get random 0's even without any beam-cut.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
    static final String PORT_NAME = "COM10"; 
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;  


    public void initialize() {
            CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
            Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

            //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAME.
            while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(PORT_NAME)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                }
            }
            if (portId == null) {
                System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
                return;
            }

            try {
                serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(), TIME_OUT);
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                is = serialPort.getInputStream();

                //console = System.console();
                serialPort.addEventListener(this);
                serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
                //serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
@Override
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            int val = 111;
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(serialPort.getInputStream());
                if (sc.hasNext()) {
                    val = Integer.parseInt(sc.next()); //sc.nextInt() didn't solved the problem either
                    cRead(val);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
                System.out.println("Error reading");
            }
        }

    }

    public synchronized void cRead(int data) {
        if (data == 0) {
            System.out.println(data);
            getTimestamp(); // Returns String
        } else {
        }

    }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `sc.hasNext()` check returning true?

Comment: @Exupery: Yes, It's returning true.